# Round number to specific multiply

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to round a number to the nearest multiple of 2.5.

For example:

```
5.5 -> 5
2.8 -> 2.5
8.21 -> 7.5
9.0 - > 10
```

How do I do it in Excel?

Comment: Divide by 2.5, then round, then multiply by 2.5? Something like: Math.round(number / 2.5) * 2.5

Comment: How to write it as excel formula?

Comment: [MROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-2f10722d-38ef-4197-be12-a3f02212e637)

Comment: @dasdasd  `=round(a1/2.5,0)*2.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro()
Dim row As Integer

For row = 1 To 4
Cells(row, 2) = Math.Round(Cells(row, 1) / 2.5) * 2.5
Next

End Sub
```

I've placed your numbers in first column, and received the output in the second column, by the code above. What you are looking for is:

```
Math.Round(someNumber / 2.5) * 2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Without **VBA**, you can use the *MROUND()* worksheet function:

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't know there was a function for that. The function can be used in VBA too, if needed, by Excel.WorksheetFunction.MRound(). Just for those that wanna know :D